# c++ find vector of element present in the string

Tags: c++, c++17

I have vector of strings. It contains some names. I need to search whether particular string is present in the vector. Eg: vector of string contains "Name" and "Age". Search string is "NameXYZ". So I have to search whether "NameXYZ" contains any of the vector element. Since one of the vector element is "Name", it should return true. Is there any possibility to achieve this without iterating.

Comment: You need to iterate in some way, but not necessary with manual loop, [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) can be used with appropriate lambda.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you added a [mcve] which does this "brute force" way with iteration, since you apparently can do that. Because there are ways to search for substrings etc, which are more efficient than plain iterating, but the devil is in the details.

Comment: Also, please confirm, "without iterating" means just not iterating the vector? So it is ok, for example, to iterate the letters in the search string, or using recursion with [a trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?

Comment: Anyway, one straightforward method using standard library as much as possible, would be to use `std::map<std::string,std::size_t>` to store the names and their indexes in the original vector. Then perform binary search on the keys of the map (because `std::map` has keys in sorted order, binary search is possible).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO.

It's impossibile to search something in a vector without iterating.

The vector is unorder and unmapped container so you need to iterating to it to find something.

I attach you this link to the cppreference site:

[std::vector - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: ...or, you need to create another data structure from the vector, then use that to do the search. This means iterating the vector (or otherwise updating the extra data structure) just once per modification, not once per search.

Comment: yes could be a solution. But however you need to iterating on vector

Comment: Well, to create a vector, you need iteration anyway. You could build the extra data structure while adding stuff to the vector, so search could be done without any *extra* iteration (depending on the details of the problem).

Comment: yes, the question seems general purpose. In special case in convenient to adopt some optimazation as you say.

Answer (score 0):

The more complex is answer is **SOMETIMES**

What you are looking for is something like a [hash set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). Or for your situation [hash map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) with Key=Name and Value=Age.
This works by defining a function that turns a string into a number, called a hash. When you want to test whether the string is in the list, you calculate what number it has. You then get a list of potential candidates and iterate through those.
If you are lucky, every string has a unique number and you need to test at most one string. You still have to search for the number, but if you use the standard container, you can be certain that it is optimized. Unless you want to spend a long time making your own, it's a simple easy win.
However, be aware that it is very hard to get any search faster than [O(Log(N))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) complexity. This method is still O(log(N)) complex under the hood, as it has to still search for the hash.